# Translation of Kähler's "Über eine bemerkenswerte Hermitesche Metrik"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, translation

Has anyone translated Erich Kähler's "[Über eine bemerkenswerte Hermitesche Metrik](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02940642)" into English or French? (Preferably, but I'll take anything.)

Comment: If you'll take anything, take German!

Comment: I suppose the identity translation counts as a translation, but I was hoping for something more.

Comment: He he, nice answer!

Comment: Even if you do not know German at all, using google "translate" and your knowledge of math involved, you should be able to translate the paper yourself in a couple of days.  

Comment: I agree with Misha. One thing I find useful is not to use Google translate but Wikipedia instead to translate mathematical terminology: for instance go to the page de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ableitung or whatever, then follow the link in the left-hand column to the English (or French) version.

Comment: Automatic translation has some problems. The great Brazilian amateur soccer player, Artur Friedenreich, was rendered as Free Country or something. It did not figure out that a proper name was involved.

Comment: One more thing: Google translates by cheating, it looks for online texts which are translations of the text you entered or of something close to it. This way you may also discover if Kaehler's paper was indeed translated to English. 

Also, Of course, Will is right, this type of translation of math is only semi-automatic. 


Comment: Google translator doesn't help with German papers because German math terminology is rather different to English, French...

Comment: @Will Jagy: I could not reproduce this; it leaves the word Friedenreich alone, likley as it is not actually a word in German. However 'Herr Müller' is translated to 'Mr. Miller'; so of course in principle you are right. Thinking about it the behavior I describe is odd, as since it capitalizes Miller it ought to know it is a name. Well, nothing is perferct, and I am off-topic, sorry.   

Comment: I see only one way out of this discussion: A contest of German-to-English translation, presided over by myself. The topic: Erich Kahler's "Über eine bemerkenswerte Hermitesche Metrik". Applicants, which everyone that commented to this post are now, will submit their best efforts in a fortnight at the latest.

Comment: Gunnar: I respectfully withdraw from the contest. But if you get stuck on a particular part of the translation, feel free to send me an email (follow the link on my userpage).

Comment: The unusual thing is that there was an early translation into Mongolian. You don't see that every day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone is still interested:
http://www.woflmao.net/publications/Kaehler1932.pdf ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160603045141/http://www.woflmao.net/publications/Kaehler1932.pdf))

Comment: Did you do this yourself? If so, at least put a line in the document about translated by ___ and perhaps a date, maybe the original title and full reference. My friend Dmitry does this sometimes from Russian, he did all that just for a three page thing that noone but I would ever see. 

Comment: I'm surprised the OP wanted a translation at all, I have not often seen a paper with such a formula-to-text ratio.

Comment: The domain name the translation was hosted on has expired, but archive.org has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20160603045141/http://www.woflmao.net/publications/Kaehler1932.pdf